# Debugging web service requests

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I'm trying to consume the external web service, and I'm able to do it using soapUI with xml.

And apparently I'm sending something else from my code, is there a way I can monitor all outgoing requests, inspect them and then forward them to the actual service?

**Update:**

The webservice is not on my machine, it sits somewhere on the internet.

**Update II:**
I downloaded wireshark, there are like milion things popping on my screen, I can't see what's what. Any better tools out there? I've used tcpMon before

Comment: In situations like these, I have used another tool, WireShark, to monitor HTTP traffic, and see the actual request sent and received. It won't forward it, but at least you'll what you are actually sending, and where. Compare it to your soapUi request.

Comment: @parakmiakos thanks, downloading it now. will try it]

Comment: https://www.wireshark.org/download.html it has some 3rd party packages listed, but I haven't used it to be sincere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) tool, provided you're running Fiddler and the website on the same machine you should be able to see the requests being fired.

There is some extra setup required to capture the service calls, have a look at this [Blog](http://blogs.telerik.com/fiddler/posts/13-01-08/capturing-traffic-from-.net-services-with-fiddler) for more details.

The parameters should be available in the headers when you inspect the request.